# Volume error when setting up kafka cluster on strimzi with EKS

Tags: kubernetes

I am a Kubernetes noob, and I wanted to deploy Kafka on Strimzi. In order to do that I followed this URL on the Strimzi website
[32.0 quicstart docs](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/0.32.0/quickstart#proc-product-downloads-str). I got everything set up but was stuck on this step **"Wait for the cluster to be deployed:**

**kubectl wait kafka/my-cluster --for=condition=Ready --timeout=300s -n my-kafka-project"** part of the documentation. Just so you know, I have 5 nodes in my AWS EKS Kubernetes cluster, those nodes being t2.micro each. I have also enabled OIDC IAM, as this solution was mentioned in stack overflow [error solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68725070/k8s-pods-failure-error-while-running-volumebinding-prebind-plugin-for-pod-a#:%7E:text=returned%20nothing.-,Enable%20OIDC%20IAM,-Enabled%20OIDC%20IAM).

The error I get is :

`Events:`

`Type     Reason            Age                From               Message`

`----     ------            ----               ----               -------`

`Warning  FailedScheduling  14s (x3 over 10m)  default-scheduler  running PreBind plugin "VolumeBinding": binding volumes:` `provisioning failed for PVC "data-my-cluster-zookeeper-0"`

or something else. I have followed everything in the documentation, step by step, command by command. What do I do?

Additional info:

- K8s version 1.27
- Strimzi version 0.32.0